# My toshiba satellite windows 8 will not let me press on mouse1 while playing a game

Tags: windows-8, laptop, mouse, toshiba-laptop

So when Im playing, I try shooting a gun and it doesnt work. But when I press mulitple times it works. Then stops working.
I need serious help. It's annoying the crap out of me.

Answer (score 0):

Try turning your touch-guard off in your touchpad settings, if you are using the touchpad try buying a mouse it will solve all your problems. Other than that you could always assign the fire button as a keyboard button such as the shift key.

Comment: Where would that be?

Comment: Go to your control panel and search for "Touchpad" and then click on touchpad settings and it should be in there

Comment: I plan on getting a mouse, but for now, I'm resolving to try to fix it. Im not sure where to turn the touch-guard off or if that means clicklock.  I go to control panel, mouse and buttons. I tried fixing it but doesn't resolve to anything

Comment: Try turning off your touchguard and if that doesnt work you can always assign the fire button to a keyboard key

Comment: I dont see touchpad.

Comment: I see mouse and add a device

Comment: I really dont want to assign my fire button to a keyboard key. It's harder that way.

Comment: Is there a touchpad icon in your notification area on your toolbar?

Comment: No, I see the name of my touchpad though

Comment: Right click it and click on settings

Comment: Synaptics V7.5 on PS/2 Port

Comment: I right clicked on it, nothing happens

Comment: try just clicking on it

Comment: Im on device settings, and I clicked settings. Which brings up properties of my touchpad.

Comment: If I click on it, it just says "Other Pointing Devices"

Comment: [link](http://forums.toshiba.com/t5/Keyboards-Touchpads-Knowledge/How-do-I-change-my-touchpad-settings-and-features-on-Window-7/ta-p/343258) try this

Comment: Im guessing touch guard and Palm Check are the same

Comment: I put it all the way to miniumum, and it wont work.

Comment: Yes, they are the same

Comment: Alright, thanks for the help. I just need a mouse to resolve this.